# Is is possible to combine multiple task from one macro timeline into one micro task?

Tags: javascript, promise, react-hooks, es6-promise

```
class stateSetter {
  cache = {};
  timeout = 0;
  set = <T>(
    params: stateSetterParams
  ) => <K extends keyof T>(newState: {
    [P in K]: T[P]
  }): void => {
    const {
      _setState
    } = params;
    this.cache = {
      ...this.cache,
      ...newState
    };
    clearTimeout(this.timeout);
    this.timeout = setTimeout(() => {
      _setState((prevState: T) => ({
        ...prevState,
        ...this.cache
      }));
      this.cache = {};
    });
  };
}
```

In the above example I use setTimeout to combine multiple `setState` from one macro timeline.

```
setState({ ... });
setState({ ... });
```

Like above.

Now if I want to use Promise (cuz it would be more efficient than setTimeout), I tried:

```
class stateSetter {
  cache = {};
  promises = [];
  set = <T>(
    params: stateSetterParams
  ) => <K extends keyof T>(newState: {
    [P in K]: T[P]
  }): void => {
    const {
      _setState
    } = params;
    this.cache = {
      ...this.cache,
      ...newState
    };
    promises.push(Promise.resolve());
    Promise.all(promises).then(() => {
      _setState((prevState: T) => ({
        ...prevState,
        ...this.cache
      }));
      this.cache = {};
      this.promises = [];
    });
  };
}
```

This doesn't work. Why? How may I modify it?

Comment: how do you want to use the promise version? can you add some examples for both?